# Scala string pattern matching for html tagged contents extraction

Tags: string, scala, pattern-matching

Given a HTML page fetched from

```
val html = io.Source.fromURL("http://example.org/aPage.html").mkString()
```

how to extract the contents wrapped within a given tag ? To illustrate this consider for instance this HTML fragment and tag `<textarea>`,

```
val html = "<p>Marginalia</p> 
            <textarea rows="3" cols="10">Contents of interest"</textarea 
            <p>More marginalia</p>"
```

how to obtain `"Contents of interest"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy ways to do this:

#### Scala XML

Add the Scala XML dependency to your project:

`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.3"`

Now you can parse your HTML code and select all `textarea` tags.

```
import scala.xml.XML
val htmlXml = XML.loadString(html)
val textareaContents = (htmlXml \\ "textarea").text
```

If your HTML is valid and want to do multiple XPath queries then this may be the better way. Also check out [this blogpost](https://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/basic-xml-processing-with-scala/) for more info on what `\\` means or how to use the Scala-XML library.

#### Regexp

Another simple way to do this is to define a regular expression and find the matches:

```
val regex = "<textarea.*>(.+)</textarea>".r
regex.findAllIn(html).map {
  match => // process match
}
```